# Upload file to sub folder under bucket with AWS iOS SDKv2

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ios

I saw an example on s3 ios sdk to upload a file with a key. However, I couldn't find any example to upload a file to sub folders under a bucket. How to specify the sub folders I want to upload to?

```
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = yourBucket;
uploadRequest.key = yourKey;
uploadRequest.body = yourDataURL;
uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    // Do something with the response
    return nil;
}];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Subfolders don't really exist in S3. Just define a key containing slashes and the parts between the slashes will be **represented** with slashes in the web console. Even though you'll see folders, it's only a key name containing slashes.

So here what you want to do is have your key contain the full destination path.